# join method on list of ints in python

Tags: python

So i was studying some example of join method in python and faced an issue
.following use of join seems clear

```
L = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
x = ','.join(L)
print(x)
```

which produce :

```
red,green,blue
```

but using same logic on list of ints cause strange issue

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = ','.join(str(L))
print(x)
```

which produce :

```
[,1,,, ,2,,, ,3,,, ,4,,, ,5,,, ,6,]
```

this can be corrected using for loop as follow

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = ','.join(str(val) for val in L)
print(x)
# Prints 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

so my question is why list of string does not need for loop to provide correct values while list of ints needs extra for loop to produce correct results?

Comment: @AbraxasvonAbrasax, `str.join()`  works on any iterable, incl. `str`, so there will be no `TypeError`

Comment: @AbraxasvonAbrasax So, you are NOT iterating over `str(L)`, you iterate over `L` itself.

Comment: @AbraxasvonAbrasax, in your comment you referred to `x = ','.join(str(L))` explicitly using `First`, `Second` when listing the problems. The OP receiving `TypeError` with `x = ','.join(L)` is exactly why they post their question - i.e. no need to tell them that - they know it and ask WHY that happens. And no, there are no redundant brackets...

Answer (score 2):

It is because `str(L)` produces string `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]'` and `join` will then join every single character of that string. The correct and clear method to do what you would like to is either yours:

```py
>>> ','.join(str(i) for i in L)
'1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

or

```py
>>> ','.join(map(str, L))
'1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

There are other methods also, but for `join` to be used you need to get list of strings `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']` instead of single string `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]'`.

Comment: strange my python version returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and not  '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]'  with quotation .using python 3.6 .

Comment: @Amir just check with `type(str(L))`

Comment: @Amir, that can't be true. You probably printed the result. The quotes that "hold" a string are never printed, that's why you probably didn't see them.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `x = ','.join(str(val) for val in L)` you are traversing the list and converting each value to string. Meanwhile, if you only use `str()`to convert a list to string, you won't be traversing the list, and the output will be wrong.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(str(L))
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

As you can see in the following example, each value of the list is a string value. On the above code the entire list is a string:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print([str(i) for i in L])
```

> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

Comment: Why does it traverse list when it is all string and it does not while its int ?

Comment: @amir Because `join` only works with strings, not int values. Please take a look at the official Python documentation.

Comment: @amir More specifically, the `[i for i in thing]` syntax is what iterates over (or traverses) the list. It's called a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Comment: @amir `str(L)` turns *the whole list* into one string; `[str(i) for i in L]` gives you a new list, consisting of each of the original list's items converted into strings individually.